# How to retrieve metadata of document set using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, csom

In my SharePoint site I have document sets with some metadata (Budget, Client Name, City ..). I want to change the default look of doc-set homepage. I want to retrieve the metadata of the current document set, show it in a content editor web part.

How do I retrieve current doc set metadata using JavaScript and based on the ID of the doc set?

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you working with?

Comment: SharePoint online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using the Document Set Properties web part

First, keep in mind that there is already a web part that automatically displays metadata from the current document set. This web part is called "Document Set Properties" and can be found in the "Document Sets" category of web parts.

The fields that it displays can be configured by navigating to Library Settings, clicking the name of your Document Set content type under Content Types, and clicking "Document Set Settings."

## Using REST or JSOM instead

If for some reason that web part is inadequate for your purposes, you can use the REST API or JavaScript client side object model to retrieve metadata about the current document set. You can obtain the ID of the current document set from the "ID" parameter in the query string section of the URL.

SharePoint provides a handy `GetUrlKeyValue()` method to easily obtain query string parameters.

#### REST

```
var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID");
var listGuid = GetUrlKeyValue("List");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/_api/lists('"+listGuid+"')/items("+itemId+")");
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept","application/json;odata=verbose");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200){
            var item = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).d;
            var title = item.Title;
            var desc = item.DocumentSetDescription;
            // You can retrieve any other properties here as necessary
        }else{
           alert("error "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

#### JSOM

```
SP.SOD.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    var listGuid = GetUrlKeyValue("List");
    var itemId = GetUrlKeyValue("ID");
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var item = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getById(listGuid).getItemById(itemId);
    clientContext.load(item);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){
             var title = item.get_item("Title");
             var desc = item.get_item("DocumentSetDescription");
             // You can retrieve any other properties here as necessary
        },
        function(sender,args){
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
    );
},"sp.js");
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your JSOM code using my propreties :
var Nom = item.get_item("Nom_client");
 var surface = item.get_item("Surface");
I am using google chrome console, I have error message when I wanna retrieve "Nom": or "surface" :
VM1248:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Nom is not defined(…)

Comment: Those variables are only "in scope" between the {curly braces} of their containing `function`. You can access them as needed from any statement of code that runs within those braces. If you need to access them from another scope, the best way is to pass them as parameters to the functions where you need to access their values. A more hazardous alternative is to make the variables globally accessible, such as by attaching them to the global  `window` object, `window.nom = item.get_item("Nom_client");`

Comment: I have problem to retrieve terms from term store :
For example this is a term from term store: "Mission_x002d_Artdesk" , it retrieve me : [object Object]
Any solution 
I've tried this code and retrieve me an error:
var mission = item.get_item('Mission_x002d_Artdesk'); 
var newsCatLabel = newsCat.get_label();
var newsCatId = newsCat.get_termGuid();

VM79099:15 Uncaught TypeError: newsCat.get_label is not a function

Comment: tahnks , I've try : var mission = item.get_item("Mission_x002d_Artdesk").get_label();
and still have error : Uncaught TypeError: item.get_item(...).get_label is not a function

Comment: I just found your new question; I'll reply with an answer there.